# how to set a Role for Sonata Admin Block

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

In Sonta Admin Dashboard, i want to display Blocks based on Roles.

I.e : a block for admin will not be displayed for Author and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in config.yml just define the roles:

```
dashboard:
    blocks:
        - { position: left, type: sonata.block.service.statistics.toparticles,class: col-md-6, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_AUTHOR] }
```

Comment: Why do you ask questions, just to answer them yourself?

Comment: I don't do that!
i write the question, and  search for the solution, when i find the solution, i simply answer my question when no one do that!

Comment: You do realize that there are timestamps on both your question and your answer, and that they are just one minute apart? If you’re trying to tell a story, you should at least get the facts straight.

Comment: Thanks for your comments :)